# How do I make additional code work after existing PHP script?

Tags: php, html

Pardon for a weird title, didn't know how to put it.
Essentially, I can't write anything after my existing PHP code (it contains a class, a couple of functions and an echo of a function). I tried basic HTML, and more PHP, none of it works.

Remembering back to when I did Python, it seems that it's a loop that's still running, thus preventing anything else from working.

My code:

```
<?php

//We're using a newer and older generation algorithms in order to create different results
//The time and date is used as a basic "salting" mechanism, which will make the number hard to determine without knowing the generation time
//I should consider using more secure generation, such as "random_int"
//EXTREMELY WIP!!!

class authGeneration
{

    private function gen($maxOne) {

        $begin_value_one = date("sih") * rand(1,100);
        $auth_value_one = mt_rand($begin_value_one, $maxOne);
        echo $auth_value_one;
    }

    private function genAdd($maxTwo) {

        $begin_value_two = date("his") + mt_rand(1000,1000000);
        $auth_value_two = rand($begin_value_two, $maxTwo);
        echo $auth_value_two;
    }

    public function finalGen() {

        $begin_value_three = date("dmY");
        $auth = $this->gen(999999999) + $this->genAdd(999999999); //No more than 999999999, no less than 100000000 (for both)
        $add = $auth + $begin_value_three;
        echo parseFloat ($add);
    }

}

function authCode() {
    $obj = new authGeneration();
    echo $obj->finalGen();
}

echo "Authentication code: "; authCode();
echo "MD5 Checksum: "; md5(authCode); //Doesn't work :(
```

The first echo of `authCode();` works, however, the line below it doesn't, regardless of what I write there. Any idea as to what the issue is? Or if it's the aforementioned "loop", how do I escape it? Feel free to outline my stupidity.

**Note**, PHP isn't my specialty, I primarily use Java and/or C# (because they're more fun than PHP), and just decided to do something fun in PHP, therefore my knowledge of the language is relatively limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the following at the end of your script.

```
echo "Authentication code: " . authCode();
echo "MD5 Checksum: " . md5(authCode());
```

I believe you're just not appending the php to the echo statement correctly as ';' indicates an end of line in PHP.

Upon further looking it looks like your 2nd instance of authCode is missing the opening and closing parenthesis.

It might be better to return a string in your authCode() function and set the result set authCode() equal to a variable so that you're not calling the authCode() funciton twice. Ex:

```
function authCode() {
    $obj = new authGeneration();
    return $obj->finalGen();
}


var $authvar = authCode();
echo "Authentication code: " . authvar;
echo "MD5 Checksum: " . md5(authvar);
```

Comment: took another look, looks like the last line should have () after authCode as it's referring to the authCode() function..

Comment: **UPDATE:** I got rid of Error 500, now it just displays the number without "Authentication code: ", and the line below still doesn't appear (refer to the above link for the live result)

Comment: Using `authvar` produces Error 500 `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR) in /var/www/html/auth.php on line 39`
**UPDATE:** Fixed the issue, the text still doesn't appear

Comment: **UPDATE:** Fixed the above issue, more issues came up (numbers are concatenated instead of being added, and the text "Authentication code: " is displayed before the actual numerical output, and the MD5 hash doesn't change at all :/)